# Facing issue in dropzonejs when deleting a file

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am using the following code to use dropzonejs:

```
$(".dropzone").dropzone({ 
        url: "/ehr/postEHRFile" , 
        addRemoveLinks: "dictRemoveFile" ,
        maxFilesize: 5,
        maxFiles: 5,
        dictDefaultMessage: '<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> \
         <span class="main-text"><img src="<?php echo URL."public/images/cloud.png"; ?>" style="width:70px;opacity:0.5;"> <br /> \
         <span class="main-text"><b>Drop Files</b> to upload</span> <br /> \
         <span class="sub-text">(or click)</span> \
        ',
        dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
        clickable: true,
        headers: { "userid" : "<?php echo $this->user['id']; ?>" }  ,
        success: function (response) {
            var x = JSON.parse(response.xhr.responseText);
            if(x.error){
                alert(x.message);
                this.removeAllFiles();
            }else{
                if($("input[name='ehr_files']").val() == ''){
                    $("input[name='ehr_files']").val(x.path+':'+x.ftype+':'+x.fname);
                }else{
                    $("input[name='ehr_files']").val($("input[name='ehr_files']").val()+','+x.path+':'+x.ftype+':'+x.fname);
                }
            }
        },
        removedfile: function(file) {
            var _ref;
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
        }
    });
```

And in `success` I'm assigning the file details into a hidden fields, such as
`ImagePath:ImageType:ImageName,ImagePath:ImageType:ImageName.......` and so on.

I am doing this to save all file details in hidden fields (maybe multiple files so using a comma to separate) and will use these to save later into a database.

When the user removes a file from the dropzonejs panel then I also need to delete it's details from the hidden fields so it won't be saved in the database.

Issues:

1) I can use `file.name` to get that file and I can delete the record from the hidden field but the file name may not be unique.

2) I also can't access `file` object in success function. If it will be possible I will add a unique id to identify.

3) I can delete if I am able to get the file index, which means 2nd number file or third number file, but I don't know how to get the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching couple of hours and trying different different concepts finally i resolved my problem. 
So sharing my updated code.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var file_detail = '';
    var file_detail_arr = '';
    $(".dropzone").dropzone({ 
        url: "/ehr/postEHRFile" , 
        addRemoveLinks: "dictRemoveFile" ,
        maxFilesize: 5,
        maxFiles: 5,
        dictDefaultMessage: '<i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> \
         <span class="main-text"><img src="<?php echo URL."public/images/cloud.png"; ?>" style="width:70px;opacity:0.5;"> <br /> \
         <span class="main-text"><b>Drop Files</b> to upload</span> <br /> \
         <span class="sub-text">(or click)</span> \
        ',
        dictResponseError: 'Server not Configured',
        clickable: true,
        headers: { "userid" : "<?php echo $this->user['id']; ?>" }  ,
        success: function (response) {

            var x = JSON.parse(response.xhr.responseText);
            if(x.error){
                alert(x.message);
                this.removeAllFiles();
            }else{
                if($("input[name='ehr_files']").val() == ''){
                    $("input[name='ehr_files']").val(x.path+':'+x.ftype+':'+x.fname);
                }else{
                    $("input[name='ehr_files']").val($("input[name='ehr_files']").val()+','+x.path+':'+x.ftype+':'+x.fname);
                }
                this.on("complete", function(file) {
                 file.id = x.path;

                });
            }
        },
        removedfile: function(file) {
            var _ref;
            var file_del_path = file.id;

            var file_str = $("input[name='ehr_files']").val();
            var file_arr =  file_str.split(',');

            for(var key in file_arr){

               file_detail = file_arr[key];
                file_detail_arr = file_detail.split(':');

                if(file_detail_arr[0] == file_del_path){
                    file_arr.splice(key, 1);
                    $("input[name='ehr_files']").val(file_arr.join(','));
                }
            }

            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;

        }
    });
```